# vue firebase error in my code "Uncaught ReferenceError: StudentsStatus is not defined"

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have an array StudentsStatus defined in the data section in my vue component. `StudentsStatus : []`.
Based on user action I fill this array with data returned from API request.
Then I set a ref to a node in firebase, if the child changed i want to updated the same row in the array with the updated data. Below is my code.

```
axios.get('http://'+ server.IP + ':' + server.port + '/assigned/' + routeid + '/' + ampm).then((data) => {
    for (var i=0; i < data.data.length ; i++) {
        //  console.log(data.data[i])
        this.StudentsStatus.push(data.data[i])
    }

    axios.get('http://'+ server.IP + ':' + server.port + '/getrouteinfo/' + routeid).then((routeInfo) => {
        this.routeinfo.Device = routeInfo.data[0].Device
        DB.ref('/studentroute/'+ this.routeinfo.Device +'/'+ this.routeinfo.ampm + '/').on("child_changed", 
            function(snapshot) {
                let StudentCHK = snapshot.val();
                let myindex = StudentCHK.serial - 1

                console.log(myindex)
                console.log(this.StudentsStatus)
            });
    },
```

Regardless of the closing brackets, I receive the above error stating that This.StudentsStatus is not defined !!!

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to access StudentsStatus from a different scope, `this` on `this.StudentsStatus` it's scoped to `function(snapshot)`

Comment: How should I access it ? My understanding this. Always refer to the one declared in the data section !!

Comment: working on the vue/component, but here you have a DB.ref function callback

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you share a link to documents where I can read how to reference a vue component variable in dB. Reference callback?  Thanks for your time

Comment: Thank you I managed